# Postgres хранить форматированный текст

Tags: php, postgresql

Захотелось хранить форматированный текст в базе. Что-то вроде

```
Сущность1:
   потомок1: свойство1
   потомок2: свойство2

Сущность2:
   потомок1: свойство1
   потомок2: свойство2
```

Вроде как поле есть xml. Но думаю формат "жирноват". Или jsonp для таких целей используют?

Поиск по тексту не планируется. Просто хочу редактировать и выводить форматированный текст в вебе.

**Мои соображения**

1. если свести задачу к двумерному массиву, то json

   INSERT INTO testdb.test (txt_json)
   VALUES ('{ "name" : "Administrator", "login" : "root", "databases" : "lol" }'::json), 
   ('{ "name" : "Administrator2", "login" : "root2", "databases" : "lol2" }'::json)

и затем

```
SELECT json_each_text ( txt_json ) FROM testdb.test
```

единственно что строки (username,Administrator) придется парсить по первой запятой.

2. Можно использовать какой нить RichText Editor

Плюсы - любой вид. Минусы - сложность реализации

3. Не пытаться хранить поле - как я сделал - поле - ссылка на wiki-страницу с описанием. То есть хранение и форматирование даны на откуп другой системе

Comment: А чем простое поле типа типа текст не устраивает?

Comment: как чем? форматирование хтмл сохранять? просто смотрю на  yaml и думаю как бы его подобие реализовать

Comment: Из вашего вопроса непонятна суть проблемы. Любые печатные символы обычное текстовое поле прекрасно сохраняет.

Comment: Если Вы хотите сделать наиболее правильно, то предлагаю использовать документо-ориентированную СУБД, например, [mongodb](https://www.mongodb.org/).

Comment: да зачем она мне. думаю json хватит за глаза

Comment: @des1roer С другой стороны при хранении в text не надо будет из форматированного текста парсить в объектную модель, а потом наоборот из объектов восстанавливать форматированный текст. И иерархическая структура потомков может оказаться жирнее и сложнее при записи/извлечении из базы. Впрочем, смотря что у Вас первично. Можно ещё сериализовать (если в php есть такой интсрумент) объект в поле типа blob или byte[] (не помню как точно в pg). Сами смотрите что Вам выгодней

Comment: @des1roer:  Вы наверно имели в виду jsonb. jsonp - это про кроссдоменые запросы (костыль для старых браузеров не поддерживающих CORS). Тип jsonb, это бинарный тип (стал доспуен в PostgreSQL 9.4), который позволяет хранить именно объектную модель, как, к примеру, в монге, а главное, вы можете "повесить" индекс на любое поле в этой модели. При использовании jsonb станет досупен дополнительный [набор операторов](http://goo.gl/NBE9kf). jsonb - это "true json". Здаётся мне, что тип json был внедрён второпях, а потому с появленем jsonb остаётся в постресе для обратной совместимости.

Comment: @des1roer:  В 9.5 появятся нативные операторы для [модификации модели](https://goo.gl/BehhsD), а пока [хранимые процедуры](https://goo.gl/27e0Ya) вам в помощь. Существет расширение для постгрес [jsquery](https://github.com/postgrespro/jsquery), которое позволяет создавать более гибкие запросы к jsonb-модели. В будущем возможно это расширение войдёт в ядро, либо его аналог. Предлагаю [посмотреть выступление Олега Барутнова](https://youtu.be/6d8mu84Ves4?t=27m22s) (core team мейнтейнер и евангелист PostgreSQL), где он рассказывает про это расширение.

Comment: оу кто-то догадался функции написать. тоже смотрел и думал как объединить несколько json

Answer (score 1):

Postgresql прекрасно умеет работать с json, по этому рекомендую использовать именно его.

Comment: и с json и c jsonb и c xml. чет я не вижу простого пути. придется ответ все равно парсить и обрабатывать. и запрос на обновление не понятно как формировать.

Comment: Поясните, что вы собрались парсить?